# R [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf in lightgbm training

Tags: machine-learning, r, lightgbm

I read through some answers, it seems many people face this message before.
The answer seems there is no further need to split the tree, so you need to adjust the super parameter to make new splitting.

However, I noticed almost every time,no matter what super param you use, the same message printed from first line to last line, the only infomation is this line,no further info.

Is there a way to let the training process more informative? I mean some useful info rather than just

```
 `[Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf in lightgbm training`
```